# How to get date format used by a client system?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, locale, date-format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retrieve browser locale from httpsession?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425081/retrieve-browser-locale-from-httpsession)

How can we get date format used by client system in a web application? Can I use javascript or anything could be done with java code?

Comment: What do you mean by date format?? Examples please

Comment: date formats are driven by locales btw

Answer (score 2):

It is not *exact* duplicate to [Retrieve browser locale from httpsession?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425081/retrieve-browser-locale-from-httpsession) but this question is relevant too.

As @MozenRath mentioned the date format depends on locale. The browser locale may be retrieved 
from request object. 
So, this code shows how to get the date format:

`DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, request.getLocale());`

Substitute `SHORT` by `LONG` to retrieve long format.

Comment: Yes I Could get the Calendar object using Locale. But can you please tell how to get the date format of client.I mean the date format their system is using. Something like M.D.Y,Y.D.M,D.M.Y etc